# How should look like a morphline for MapReduceIndexerTool?

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce, morphline

I want to search through a lot of logs (about 1 TB in size, placed on multiple machines) efficiently.

For that purpose, I want to build an infrastructure composed of Flume, Hadoop and Solr. Flume will get the logs from a couple of machines and will put them into HDFS.

Now, I want to be able to index those logs using a map reduce job in order to be able to search through them using Solr. I found that [MapReduceIndexerTool](https://github.com/bfs/solr-mapreduce-indexer/blob/master/src/main/java/org/apache/solr/hadoop/MapReduceIndexerTool.java) does this for me, but I see that it needs a **morphline**.

I know that a morphline, in general, performs a set of operations on the data it takes but what kind of operations should I perform if I want to use the MapReduceIndexerTool?

I can't find any example on a morphline adapted for this map reduce job.

Thank you respectfully.

Comment: Find link inside this section http://flume.apache.org/FlumeUserGuide.html#morphlinesolrsink

Comment: Have added a reference to cloudera doc, which is having similar use case example. Hope it helps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cloudera has a [guide](http://cloudera.github.io/cdk/docs/current/cdk-morphlines/index.html) which is having almost similar use case given under `morphline`.

[image]

> In this figure, a Flume Source receives syslog events and sends them
>   to a Flume Morphline Sink, which converts each Flume event to a record
>   and pipes it into a readLine command. The readLine command extracts
>   the log line and pipes it into a grok command. The grok command uses
>   regular expression pattern matching to extract some substrings of the
>   line. It pipes the resulting structured record into the loadSolr
>   command. Finally, the loadSolr command loads the record into Solr,
>   typically a SolrCloud. In the process, raw data or semi-structured
>   data is transformed into structured data according to application
>   modelling requirements.

The use case given in the example is what production tools like `MapReduceIndexerTool`, `Apache Flume Morphline Solr Sink` and `Apache Flume MorphlineInterceptor` and Morphline Lily HBase Indexer are running as part of their operation, as outlined in the following figure:

[image]

Comment: This doesn't really answer the question *what kind of operations should I perform*... unless you are referring to the `grok`  command

Comment: @cricket_007 the link has the details on how to do that including the sample code. Can't replicate the tutorial here, so has put an abstract and a possible algo. OP still needs to refer the complete cloudera guide to get through.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. The  answer is somehow correct and complete. The point is that I already read the documentation that you mentioned but now I spent a bit more time on it. However I have one question: what is the actual purpose of the morphline? It just transforms the data into tokens in order to be easily indexable? Am I correct?

Comment: `morphline` in bigdata world is similar to `ETL` in classical world. The purpose of morphline is to transform data from one state to another using a program/command. There have been development on this line to make it config driven and standardize; but I feel it is still emerging. May be someday, we will have a morphline framework which support `plug-your-transformation` in a better way.

Comment: okay, great, but I still need a clear answer to my question. The purpose of a morphline in the case of MapReduceIndexerTool is to transform the data into an easily indexable format? What is it's actual purpose when we want to index data using that map reduce job?

Comment: @Cosmin HDFS (or Flume) records are taken one by one and parsed into a format appropriate for the configured destination. In your case, Solr. The morphline file defines the pipeline, and mapreduce indexer knows how to run distributed across the data and read that morphline  configuration

Answer (score 1):

In general, in morplhine you only need to read your data, convert it to solr documents and then call `loadSolr` to create index.

For example, this is moprhline file I used with MapReduceIndexerTools to upload Avro data into Solr:

```
SOLR_LOCATOR : {
  collection : collection1
  zkHost : "127.0.0.1:2181/solr"
}
morphlines : [
  {
    id : morphline1
    importCommands : ["org.kitesdk.**"]    
    commands : [
      {
        readAvroContainer {}
      }    
      {
        extractAvroPaths {
          flatten : false
          paths : {
            id : /id
            field1_s : /field1
            field2_s : /field2
          }
        }
      }
      {
        sanitizeUnknownSolrFields {
          solrLocator : ${SOLR_LOCATOR}
        }
      }
      {
        loadSolr {
          solrLocator : ${SOLR_LOCATOR}
        }
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

When run it reads avro container, maps avro fields to solr document fields, removes all other fields and uses provided Solr connection details to create index. It's based on [this tutorial](https://www.cloudera.com/documentation/enterprise/5-7-x/topics/search_morphline_example.html#csug_topic_8_1).

This is command I'm using to index files and merge them to running collection:

```
sudo -u hdfs hadoop --config /etc/hadoop/conf \
jar /usr/lib/solr/contrib/mr/search-mr-job.jar org.apache.solr.hadoop.MapReduceIndexerTool \
--morphline-file /local/path/morphlines_file  \
--output-dir hdfs://localhost/mrit/out \
--zk-host localhost:2181/solr \
--collection collection1 \ 
--go-live \
hdfs:/mrit/in/my-avro-file.avro
```

Solr should be configured to work with HDFS and collection should exist.

All this setup works for me with Solr 4.10 on CDH 5.7 Hadoop.